# Is Noam Chomsky correct when he says the rules of a language are made up?

Tags: grammar, linguistics

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=hdUbIlwHRkY#t=575), Chomsky says that the rules of a language are pretty much artificial. How correct is he in regard to English? If what he says is correct, doesn't that undermine nearly every 'correct' answer given on this site?

Comment: If you call them "rules" then sure, they're made up. If you call them "conventions" then they're more real. Linguists don't like to call any language "incorrect" but they will call it "nonstandard" or "nonconventional".

Comment: Also think about this: Let's invent a game and make up a rule.  If you cross the line carrying the ball you're out. Why? because we decided so.  We just made that up, but now when you're playing our game, you're out if you cross the line with the ball.

Comment: Chomsky is well-known as a champion of descriptivism. Does this site have a standard link on [prescriptivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) vs [descriptivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description)?

Answer (score 3):

Many of the rules are artificial in at least two senses.

In one sense, some  are artificial in that they were the natural form for speakers of one variety of English, but they have been imposed on speakers of other varieties. For the speakers of these varieties, they were originally artificial. One example of this is the -s suffix for the third person singular of the present simple.  Once normal only in the north of England, by the fifteenth century it was beginninng to appear in the south (See Baugh and Cable, 1993, *A History of the English Language*), and today it is the standard 'correct' form. In recent years, I have heard people who  use the suffix for all persons of the verb, and people who use it for none. This is perfectly natural and  'correct' in their home dialect, but they are taught at school that it is 'substandard' or 'incorrect' and have to learn to use the (for them) artificial standard usage.

In another sense some rules are artificial in that they were never a natural part part of most speakers of any variety of English. An example of this is the (now largely discredited) 'rule' about not splitting infinitives. This rule appears to have originated in the mid 19th century. It may have been the practice of some writers not to split infinitives, but nobody before about [1840](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive#History_of_the_term) thought this was incorrect. Once writers on English decided that splitting infintives was incorrect, the artificial rule was accepted as such for well over a century. As late as 1996, Burchfield, in his revision of Fowler's *Modern English Usage*advises ("Avoid splitting infinitives wherever possible" (p. 738).

Answer (score 1):

He means "artificial" in the sense of "arbitrary". That is, there is no particular reason why "the ball red" is standard in some languages while "the red ball" is standard in others.

However, just because rules are arbitrary doesn't mean you can't determine what is or is not correct according to the rules. Parking restrictions are quite arbitrary too, but it's usually easy to tell if you're breaking the rules or not.

Likewise, just because English is arbitrary doesn't mean that one can't determine what is or is not grammatical, standard, aesthetically pleasing, et cetera. So, don't worry, this site is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

No language begins with rules. In the course of time speakers of a language find a sytem of speaking that is accepted by all - more or less.  And as grammar is only description of how a language system works Chomsky's statement has only limited value. Of course, there are cases, where experts as Samuel Johnson and others discussed problems of language and made suggestions about things that are not so good. Sometimes these suggestions were observed. But, in the end, it is the speakers who decide how they speak and write.